# How should I correct the code to get rid of these "value not used" warnings?

Tags: android, eclipse, location

These are the error messages I am getting please advise.

The value of the field LocationListActivity.adapter is not used

The value of the field LocationListActivity.lv1 is not used

The value of the field LocationListActivity.titleString is not used

```
public class LocationListActivity extends ExpandableListActivity {

private ArrayAdapter<String> adapter = null;
private String name;
private ArrayList<List<LocationData>> locations; //Array list of all locations
private ArrayList<LocationData> locationList; // locations for each group
private ListView lv1;
private ArrayList<String> locationSection = new ArrayList<String>();
private ArrayList<String> sectionLocations = new ArrayList<String>();
private ArrayList<ArrayList<String>> allLocations = new ArrayList<ArrayList<String>>();
private String titleString;
private ExpandableListAdapter mAdapter;
private Button search;

@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState); 
    setContentView(R.layout.location_list_activity);

    search = (Button)findViewById(R.id.search_button);
    search.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {
        public void onClick(View v) {
            startActivity(new Intent(LocationListActivity.this, LocationListSearchActivity.class));
        }
    });

    //PARSE locations.xml
    try { 
        this.locations = new ArrayList<List<LocationData>>();
        this.locationList = new ArrayList<LocationData>();

        XmlResourceParser xrp = this.getResources().getXml(R.xml.locations);

        LocationData currentLocation = null;
        while(xrp.getEventType() != XmlResourceParser.END_DOCUMENT) {
            currentLocation = new LocationData();
            if(xrp.getEventType() == XmlResourceParser.START_TAG) {
                if(xrp.getName().equals("section")) {
                    locationSection.add(xrp.getAttributeValue(null, "title"));

                } 
                else if(xrp.getName().equals("location")) {
                    currentLocation.setBuilding((xrp.getAttributeValue(null, "building")));
                    name = xrp.getAttributeValue(null, "name");

                    sectionLocations.add(name);
                    currentLocation.setName(name);
                    currentLocation.setDetailName((xrp.getAttributeValue(null, "detailName")));
                    currentLocation.setLat(Double.parseDouble(xrp.getAttributeValue(null, "lat")));
                    currentLocation.setLng(Double.parseDouble(xrp.getAttributeValue(null, "lng")));
                    currentLocation.setPhone(xrp.getAttributeValue(null, "phone"));
                    locationList.add(currentLocation);
                }
            }
            else if(xrp.getEventType() == XmlResourceParser.END_TAG) {
                if(xrp.getName().equals("section")) {
                    allLocations.add(new ArrayList<String>(sectionLocations));
                    sectionLocations.clear();
                    locations.add(new ArrayList<LocationData>(locationList));
                    locationList.clear();
                }
            }
            xrp.next();
        }   
        xrp.close();}
        catch (XmlPullParserException  xppe) {} 
        catch (IOException e) {}

     // Set up our adapter
        mAdapter = new MyExpandableListAdapter();
        setListAdapter(mAdapter);


}


public class MyExpandableListAdapter extends BaseExpandableListAdapter {

    public Object getChild(int groupPosition, int childPosition) {
        return allLocations.get(groupPosition).get(childPosition);
    }

    public long getChildId(int groupPosition, int childPosition) {
        return childPosition;
    }

    public int getChildrenCount(int groupPosition) {
        return allLocations.get(groupPosition).size();
    }

    public TextView getGenericView() {
        // Layout parameters for the ExpandableListView
        AbsListView.LayoutParams lp = new AbsListView.LayoutParams(
                ViewGroup.LayoutParams.FILL_PARENT, 80);

        TextView textView = new TextView(LocationListActivity.this);
        textView.setLayoutParams(lp);
        // Center the text vertically
        textView.setGravity(Gravity.CENTER_VERTICAL | Gravity.LEFT);
        // Set the text starting position
        textView.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.button_click);
        textView.setTypeface(null, android.graphics.Typeface.BOLD);
        textView.setTextColor(0xFF000000);
        textView.setPadding(55, 0, 0, 0);
        return textView;
    }

    public View getChildView(int groupPosition, int childPosition, boolean isLastChild,
            View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
        TextView textView = getGenericView();
        textView.setText(getChild(groupPosition, childPosition).toString());
        textView.setTypeface(null, android.graphics.Typeface.NORMAL);
        return textView;
    }

    public Object getGroup(int groupPosition) {
        return locationSection.get(groupPosition);
    }

    public int getGroupCount() {
        return locationSection.size();
    }

    public long getGroupId(int groupPosition) {
        return groupPosition;
    }

    public View getGroupView(int groupPosition, boolean isExpanded, View convertView,
            ViewGroup parent) {
        TextView textView = getGenericView();
        textView.setText(getGroup(groupPosition).toString());
        return textView;
    }

    public boolean isChildSelectable(int groupPosition, int childPosition) {
        return true;
    }

    public boolean hasStableIds() {
        return true;
    }

}

  public boolean onChildClick (ExpandableListView parent, View v, int groupPosition, int childPosition, long id) {
    Intent i = new Intent( LocationListActivity.this, LocationInfoActivity.class );

        i.putExtra("name", locations.get(groupPosition).get(childPosition).getName());
        i.putExtra("building", locations.get(groupPosition).get(childPosition).getBuilding());
        i.putExtra("detailName", locations.get(groupPosition).get(childPosition).getDetailName());
        i.putExtra("lat", locations.get(groupPosition).get(childPosition).getLat());
        i.putExtra("lng", locations.get(groupPosition).get(childPosition).getLng());
        i.putExtra("phone", locations.get(groupPosition).get(childPosition).getPhone());
        startActivity(i);
    return false;
  }

@Override
public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu){
    MenuInflater inflater = this.getMenuInflater();
    inflater.inflate(R.menu.menu_home, menu);
    return true;
}

 //Called when user selects a menu item;
@Override
public boolean onOptionsItemSelected( MenuItem item ){

    switch(item.getItemId()) {
    case R.id.menu_search:
        startActivity(new Intent(this, LocationListSearchActivity.class));
        finish();
    break;  
    case R.id.menu_about:
        startActivity(new Intent(this, AboutActivity.class));
        finish();
    break;              
    }   
    return true;
}
```

}

Comment: simply delete the values/variables that aren't beeing used.

Answer (score 3):

You can use

```
@SuppressWarnings("unused")
```

**Note:** Similar thing happened to me. I had variables that all was used but warning still appeared. So in this case this approach is very good.

But if you have variables which you  already not using nowhere, i recommend to remove them or comment them.

Answer (score 1):

You could remove or comment out those variables.  If you don't want to do that you can also change the warnings within Eclipse.

Answer (score 1):

There have been times where I had variables that I KNOW were used and I couldn't figure out why it kept saying they were not. For some reason, certain errors in other part of the program might be making that happen. Alternately, if you are not going to use what it has highlighted, then I would just delete it.